# How to check if the element is checked

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener, checked

I have this code that that should add different classes to the following elements depending on whether the element before them is checked or not, but for some reason it either gives me the undefined or static state either true or false, which doesn't change regardless whether I click the element or not.

this is the code:

```
function triggerLedDependency() {
    if (userSelection.led.mitLED.checked) {
        document.getElementById("ohneMotorWrapper").classList.add("disabled-option");

    } else {
        return document.getElementById("ohneMotorWrapper").classList.add("enabled-option");
    }
}
```

what should be changed?

Comment: I can't even guess what that is : `userSelection.led.mitLED` if there's more code you should post it as a [mcve]

Comment: It makes so that after clicking on the "mitLED" option, the "ohneMotorWrapper" is not possible to click. the problem is that the code itself is very big to post and the classes are done in German, because of the origin of the company. The information is all written in .js files and that is how they are generated. The problem is that the code only either sees undefined when it comes down to checking whether the apropriate element is selected or not or statically true or false. Hope that answered your question

Comment: Additionally, userSelection creates a new object and afterwards goes the specifiation of the certain part of the object. mitLED is the one of the items of led which is an object created by userSelection